Indy Transport 6335 - Alternative/Updated Instructions Scan?
Classic Town set 6335 Indy Transport has the following text on the Bricklink inventory page (at the very bottom):

Redesigned during production. There are at least 2 different versions
of instructions for this set. The differences for the second version
are indicated in this inventory in the Alternate Items section with
Match ID 99.
Quick overview of redesign: On the upper deck of the trailer a white 2
x 4 plate is replaced by a white 4 x 4 plate and some of the white
hinges are doubled up. A black 4 x 8 plate is added above the trailer
wheels and a black 2 x 4 technic plate is added to the tractor where
the trailer attaches.

All of the instructions scans available in the usual places on the web, Picsl, letsbuilditagain, etc. all have the original version of the instructions pre-redesign.
From the Bricklink description and the alternative parts list, it is mostly possible to understand/guess how the redesign would work but I would really like to see a version the updated instructions.
A quick way to determine the version is by looking at page 15, step 4. In the original instructions only one set of hinge plates are used on each side whereas, according to the Bricklink description, in the updated version there are two sets of hinges per side.

Does anyone know of a scan of the updated version of the instructions online or happen to have a copy they would be willing to scan?

The version of this set I own seems to have the updated instructions, sadly a few of the pages have seen better days, it was a much-loved set!


Edit: Found more pages showing the 4x8 plate and 4x2 technic plate on the truck




This is excellent, thank you! Do you happen to have the part of the instructions where the red axels are added to the trailer? In the originals they are added in step 8 but since the black 4x8 is added in the updated instructions at that step I am still missing exactly where the trailer axels should be positioned in the updated build. I assume they just go below the green 1x4 plates as before except with the 4x8 plate between them this time.

I do (just about!) Added picture to my answer. Yes they are attached as you described in step 21.

@logicalfox Thank you - this is exactly what Bricks.SE was made for.

@logicalfox Perfect! Thanks again!
